# Django: Accessing full User information via ManyToMany field

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

everyone- I'm new to Django and working on my first big project and I'm having trouble with accessing default Django User model information via a ManyToMany relationship.  I've spent a great deal of time searching and can't crack it.

**models.py**

```
class Event(models.Model):
  event_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, unique=True)
  #etc...

class School(models.Model):
  user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
  event = models.ForeignKey(Event, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
  #etc...
```

My url contains the id  of the Event, so...

**views.py**

```
def schools(request, pk):
   event = Event.objects.get(id=pk)
   school = School.objects.filter(event=event)
   return render(request, 'accounts/schools.html', {'event':event, 'school':school})
```

**template**

```
{% for school in school %}
   <tr>
      <td>{{school.name}}</td>
      <td>{{school.user.all}}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

On my template, I'm able to use {{school.user.all}} to get me a Queryset displayed with the username of each User, but I want the first_name and last_name and can't see to figure out how to get that..

Thank you for any suggestions.  I greatly appreciate your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include both schools and users to your context.

You can do this with a dictionary. Add each school as a key, and users of each school as its values. Then you can pass this dictionary to your template.

View function:

```
def schools(request):
    school_dict = dict()
    schools = School.objects.all()
    for school in schools:
        school_dict[school] = school.user.all()
    return render(request, 'accounts/schools.html', {'schools': school_dict})
```

And in your template:

```
{% for school, users in schools.items %}
    <h3>{{ school.title }}</h3>
    <table>
    {% for user in users %}
        <tr>
        <td>{{ user.first_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.last_name }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your time.  I may have not been clear on the ultimate goal.  I need a template that looks up an event and then lists all schools and the users attached to those schools via the ManyToMany relationship.  I think I'm confused how your example would attach the users to their specific schools?

Comment: You can pass a dictionary in this format: `{school: [users]}`. Add all schools as keys to this dictionary, and add all users of those schools as the value in the type of array. Pass this dictionary in your context. Then iterate over all keys of the dictionary and all values of those keys (users) in your template. Iterate over the values (users) too, and print their names. Let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: Alright, I've spent a couple hours trying different things and can't seem to get it right.  If you want to spread the breadcrumbs a little closer to the solution or give me another clue that would be awesome.  I'll let you know if I really surrrender, as well...

Comment: Hey @MattSchucker! I'm glad that you tried and did not give up. I updated my answer with a working solution. Let me know if it works for you. Thanks!

Comment: @luke- I definitely don't give up easily!  I enjoy the thrill of trying to figure things out myself (with my friend google...)  Your solution is awesome- I got it working but have trouble implementing it exactly like I need to.  I left out in the original post that I actually don't want to use all school objects, I want to separate it by another attribute of school: level (MS or HS).  I keep trying to play around with different versions of     middle = School.objects.filter(event=event, level='MS')   but can't figure out how to work with the resulting queryset since I need all objects...

Comment: Happy to hear that it works. If the answer solves your question you should accept the answer. You can always ask new questions for your other specific needs. Thank you.

Comment: Also, if an answer is useful you can always upvote. It is just a free click but motivates the community to help more. :) Thanks!

Comment: I was finally able to crack it completely as I was looking to.  I am very grateful for your help!  Answer accepted and upvoted!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add this to my school model to get what I wanted:

```
    def director(self):
        test = ",".join([str(p) for p in self.user.all()])
        user = User.objects.get(username=test)
        return user.first_name + " " + user.last_name
```

**HOWEVER:** if there is more than one user associated with "School" it displays blank